# Using req.params across express middle-wares

Tags: express

I have an express code block as follows,

```js
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// server application
var app = new express();
app.use('/:user', bodyParser.json());

// application level validations
app.use('/:user', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('[application]', req.params);
    req.params.user = parseInt(req.params.user);
    next();
});

// level-1 router
var router1 = express.Router({
    mergeParams: true
});

// level-1 router registered with application
app.use('/:user/one/:a', router1);

// router level-1 validations
router1.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('[router-1]', req.params);
    req.params.a = parseInt(req.params.a);
    next();
});

// level-2 router
var router2 = express.Router({
    mergeParams: true
});

// level-2 router registered with level-1 router
router1.use('/two/:b', router2);

// router level-2 validations
router2.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('[router-2]', req.params);
    req.params.b = parseInt(req.params.b);
    next();
});

// level-2 router has a resource
router2.get('/func', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('Done!');
});

// start the application
app.listen(2345);
```

Here, one can assume that every middle-ware does some validations on path parameters and updates the properties in place. Say, these middle-ware validates value type and updates the value as respective type, instead of keeping as string (like AJV doing when `{ coerceTypes: true }`).

With the above code block, I expect the updated values in `req.params` across middle-wares, but not happening. That is, for a call like this `http://localhost:2345/123/one/1/two/2/func`, in console I expect...

```js
[application] {
    user: '123'
}

[router-1] {
    user: 123, a: '1'
}

[router-2] {
    user: 123, a: 1, b: '2'
}
```

But I get...

```js
[application] {
    user: '123'
}

[router-1] {
    user: '123', a: '1'
}

[router-2] {
    user: '123', a: '1', b: '2'
}
```

I need help to achieve the expected output.

Comment: IIRC the params are parsed each time.

Comment: You are console logging the `req.params` before parsing them, are you sure you want to display before parsing them to `int`?

Comment: @Muhammad Zeeshan...here subsequent line of log is the concern,  which is after earlier parseInt() call.

Comment: @Dave Newton...Is there an option to make parsing once. I guess restify preserves `req.params` across levels of routers.

Comment: I doubt there's a built-in option for this, but I don't *know* there isn't.